# radialGravityField goes nuts after a while

Tags: macos, swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody, skfieldnode

I'm trying to create a SpriteKit game using Swift that looks somewhat like a 2D gravity simulator, but when my objects approach a bit they go to the opposite direction with crazy speeds.

This may be related with the `minimumRadius`, `categoryBitMask` or `fieldBitMask` properties on the field and physicsBody, but I don't know exactly.

**Here's the relevant code:**

```
override func mouseDown(theEvent: NSEvent) {

    let location = theEvent.locationInNode(self)

    let sprite = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 5)
    sprite.fillColor = SKColor(red: 0, green: 0.5, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
    sprite.strokeColor = SKColor.clearColor()
    sprite.position = location
    sprite.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 5)
    let gravityField = SKFieldNode.radialGravityField()
    //gravityField.minimumRadius = 5
    sprite.addChild(gravityField)

    self.addChild(sprite)
}
```

**And a gif demonstration of the problem:**

[image: Problem demonstration]

As you can see, the distance that the objects need to move to trigger the issue seems to be random.

Comment: Interesting... Is there a property where you can manipulate the magnitude of the radial gravity?

Comment: You can use the `strength` property. Lowering it seems to mitigate the effects. If you set the `strength = 0.01` and `minimumRadius = 5` any strange effects seem to go (mostly). Obviously that's not a proper solution but perhaps it can help uncover the true cause of the weirdness.

Comment: @ABakerSmith true, this may be a workaround.

Comment: @ABakerSmith I've noticed that setting strength to a low value will eventually cause the problem to come back if you create lots of bodies, since the gravity strength will increase.